# how Hub Sites can be created/configured on SharePoint Online without using PowerShell. need to do it by online admin console

Tags: sharepoint-online

how Hub Sites can be created/configured on SharePoint
Online without using PowerShell. I am looking for a way to
configure my existing Team/Communications sites using the online admin
console and not powershell.

Answer (score 0):

You can register/unregister a site as a Hubsite from the SharePoint Online admin centre, make sure you are using the new admin centre experience.

You should see the big blue "try now" button at the top of the page.

From here, when selecting an active site you should see the Hub site option appear on the ribbon.